# Telephone number category using regex pattern

Tags: java, regex, phone-number

I want to get user input for telephone numbers. I have 2 number categories Golden and Normal. When the user enter certain pattern of a telephone number, the system will automatically determine it as Golden or Normal. I'm having problem to code certain pattern. One of the Golden Pattern number is like this: AB001234 where AB is number like 12,23,34,45,56,67,78 and 89. Here what I got so far.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Enter Telephone Number");
    String nophone = userinput.next();

    String Golden = "(\\d)(\\1)002345|(\\d*)12345$";
    //I want to add AB001234 pattern to the line above but I don't know how.


    if (nophone.matches(Golden)) {
        System.out.println("Golden");
    }


    else {
        System.out.println("Normal");
    }
    }
```

I'm not sure do I really have to use regex or not.
One more question, you can see the first part of String Golden is without $ while the second part has $. I'm not sure the effect if I put or remove the $ symbol.

Comment: What about Normal pattern? How do they look?

Comment: Other than the Golden Pattern is Normal pattern. It doesn't have specific pattern

Comment: Still don't get the *rule* for golden patterns... is it golden if and only if `B = A+1`?

Comment: @Andreas_D sorry I don't really get what you mean. :(

Answer (score 3):

`(\\d)(\\1)` does not check for the sequence like `12`, `23` and so on.. Rather it checks for two smae consecutive digits like `11`, `22`, `33`, ...

To check for sequence, you would have to do it explicitly using `Pipe(|)` - 
`(12|23|34|45|...)`

So, your pattern for `Golden Number` should be like this: -

```
^(?:12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89)001234$
```

`(?:..)` - Means a `non-capturing group`. It will not be captured as a numbered group in your pattern.

**NOTE: -** If the length of your `sequence` is varying, then `Regex` is not an appropriate way to match them.

For your second question, `$` denotes the end of the string. So, the pattern with `$` at the end, will be matched at the end of the string. Also, `Caret (^)` is there to match the beginning of the string.

**For e.g.: -**

- `abc$` matches the string `"asdfabc"`, but not `"sdfabcf"`.
- `^abc` matches the string `"abcfsdf"`, but not `"sdfabcf"`.
- `^abc$` only matches the string `"abc"`, because it is the only string, that starts and ends with `"abc"`.

You can go through the following links to learn more about `Regexp`: -

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Also, `.matches()` only matches the *entire* string and fails on substrings; that might also be relevant here.

Comment: Yeah that's also a valid point. To match your regex with a substring, you would need to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` class, and `Matcher#find` method.

Comment: Yeah I've tried using the .matches() method. But not really sure how to proceed since I'm so new to Java.
Anyway super thanks.

Comment: As said in first comment, if your telephone number is inside some string, your `matches` will not work. you should use `Matcher.find` method with the pattern. See the tutorial links I have given. You will learn them better in those links.

Comment: @RohitJain what does (?: means in your answer above?

Comment: @MistaPlatoniC.. Ah! Sorry.. should have mentioned that. That means a `non-capturing` group. If you don't want to capture your pattern, and still you want to group them, then make it `non-capturing` by using: - `(?:)` instead of `()`

Answer (score 1):

To get this:

> AB001234 where AB is number like 12,23,34,45,56,67,78 and 89. Here
>   what I got so far

The regex would look like:

```
^(12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89)001234$
```

The `$` symbol means end of the string. This means that if there is any aditional character after the last one, the string won't match the Regex.

The `^` symbol means the begining of the string.

For further information, please, check the [Summary of regular-expression constructs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) at the Javadoc API.